# Solving 4th order ODE of a function evaluated at two different points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, numerical-methods

I'm trying to solve the ODE of a cantilever beam with a particular loading function. How does one solve a differential equation of the following form, either analytically or numerically (if the latter, how would one go about putting this into a conventional solver)?

$$ \frac{d^{4}y(x)}{dx^4} = \frac{a^2}{(1-y(x)-y(1-x))^2}$$

where $x$ is limited to the range [0, 1] and $a$ is a real constant. If it helps guide a solution, I have boundary constraints on my problem that $y(0) = y'(0) = 0$ and that $y''(1) = y'''(1) = 0$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the functions $f(x)=y(x)+y(1-x)$ and $g(x)=y(x)-y(1-x)$. Then $g^{(4)}=0$ and $$f^{(4)}(x)=\frac{2a^2}{(1-f(x))^2}.$$

You get also  a doubled amount of boundary conditions from $y(x)=\frac12(f(x)+g(x))$ and $y(1-x)=\frac12(f(x)-g(x))$, so that in the end you get a full boundary value problem in state dimension $8$ with ordinary differential equations.

Comment: Thanks, @Lutz Lehmann! That's a really clever way to break down the problem!